# Get a key by value in Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an input string in language 1 and I'd like to find what key it corresponds to in my `Localizable.strings`. Later I will use this key to retrieve its value in language 2.

How can I find a key by value?

Comment: is the input string is predefined one or depends on user input?

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  let stringsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Localizable", ofType: "strings")
        var dictionary = NSDictionary (contentsOfFile: stringsPath ?? "")

        if let temp = dictionary?.allValues.filter({$0 as? String == "Your Value to be searched"}), temp.count > 0 {
            print("nice found")
        }
```

Check with above code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know I can reach Localizable like that.